# How to organize javascript file into smaller pieces?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have one large external javascript file that is used on the page. I currently wrap the code in a self-invoking function because I have other sections that are loaded using ajax tabs, so I want to avoid naming clashes with those other external js files.

The code in the file is organized like below. I would like to split some of the code inside the plannerTab namespace into smaller files, yet still have it be part of that namespace.

How could I do this? Or, do you guys recommend a different approach? Thanks!

```
// Document Ready
$(function ()
{
    // initializes table
    plannerTab.plannerTable.init();
});


var plannerTab = (function ()
{
    // All the code for the page is in here. I would like to extract sections 
    // from in here and put them into their own external files while still keeping 
    // the namespacing
}();
```

**Update**

How could I separate parts from within the plannerTab variable into smaller external js files, and still maintain that they are part of the plannerTab namespace? A small example below.

```
// Scope: plannerTab.config - Would like to store configuartion into a separate file
    var config = {

        selectors: {
            tableId: '#plannerTable',
            addTaskId: '#AddTask',
            editTaskSelector: '#plannerTable .edit',
            dateFilterSelector: '#plannerTable_TimeFilter li',
            deleteTaskClass: '.delete',
            searchFilter: '#plannerTable_filter',
            selectedDateFilter: 'selected-dateFilter',
            taskCellSelector: '#plannerTable .task-col',
            taskClass: '.taskId'
        },

        urls: {
            addTaskFormURL: '/Planner/Planner/LoadAddTaskForm',
            editTaskFormURL: '/Planner/Planner/LoadEditTaskForm',
            deleteTaskURL: '/Planner/Planner/DeleteTask',
            getTasksByDateRangeURL: '/Planner/Planner/GetTasksByDateRange',
            viewTaskURL: '/Planner/Planner/ViewTask'
        }
    };
```

Comment: Is this to ease development or for deployment? I'll suggest that you keep one file, to reduce HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example (from google)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function importScript(url){
    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.type="text/javascript";
    tag.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
}
window.onload = function(){
    // imports go here
    importScript("foo.js"); // example
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that plannerTab becomes an object return result of the self executing function.  If you need to add properties or methods to that object dynamically, you can take a look at jQuery.extend() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

You would need to modify the external JS to use the jQuery extend method to add onto existing properties and methods of plannerTab.  As long as you keep plannerTab a global variable, you will continue adding to it as you import more external js files.

If you are using the module pattern to maintain private variables in plannerTab, be sure to test how those values behave once you use jQuery.extend().

Comment: yes, plannerTab is an object that holds many other objects and such, such page events, configurations, etc... Would it be better to add this variable to the Jquery object or add more properties to the object itself (is that possible?)

Comment: You can add properties to the object by simply using dot notation 

`plannerTab.newProperty = "some value"`  

If you'd like to add several properties, just use $.extend()

Comment: I'm a bit slow today :) I just can't wrap my head around how I would do the above (see update section in post). Do I make my self-invoking function empty and tack on new methods and properties and put them into separate files?